# Query is very slow and resources consuming

Tags: mysql, wordpress, post, taxonomy

The following query in file wp-includes/taxonomy.php line number 4000 is very slow and resources consuming when there are big amount of users that completing the functional operation in the same time on my site.
Can we do something about it?

Find attached image of query:
[Click here to see image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n26by.png)

```
$count += (int) $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->term_relationships, $wpdb->posts WHERE $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id AND post_status IN ('" . implode( "', '", $post_statuses ) . "') AND post_type IN ('" . implode( "', '", $object_types ) . "') AND term_taxonomy_id = %d", $term ) );
```

`$count += (int) $wpdb->get_var( $wpdb->prepare( "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $wpdb->term_relationships, $wpdb->posts WHERE $wpdb->posts.ID = $wpdb->term_relationships.object_id AND post_status IN ('" . implode( "', '", $post_statuses ) . "') AND post_type IN ('" . implode( "', '", $object_types ) . "') AND term_taxonomy_id = %d", $term ) );`

Need to optimize this query

Comment: What does the execution plan tell you about this? Also, be warned that your query is highly vulnerable for SQL injections. Have a look at how to use prepared statements **properly** to avoid getting hacked (hint: using `implode` to put a raw string into a query is not safe)